# Objectify, does creating a key cause datastore read?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, objectify

When we create a key in objectify from a web safe string, is Objectify hitting the datastore in anyway. For example when we do ...

```
Key.create(webSafeString):
```

Is Objectify using some idempotent algorithm to create the key, or is it dependent on what is stored in the datastore, or what entities have been registered? What exceptions can we expect to be thrown?

Also, if it is reading the datastore, what is the cost?

Comment: Reading the source code, Jesus. Can't find the source for com.google.storage.onestore.v3.OnestoreEntity.Reference. Dammit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Creating a Key from a websafe string is just protobuf manipulation, and should not involve an RPC to Google's service layer.

Comment: Is it the same if you call getId() or getParent() on that said key?

Comment: Those methods are just getters for private fields.